# PHP ZipArchive Issue

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

it's the first time I'm using PHP to make ZIP archives. However, I am not getting any zip files even though no error is being outputted. I did `echo $zip->close` and it gave **1**.

Can someone help me?

```
/* Create zip folder */
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zipCreate = $zip->open("newarchive.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);

if($zipCreate !== TRUE) {
    die("Zip folder creation failed");
}

$zip->addFile("test.txt", "test.txt");
$zip->addFile("helllo.txt", "helllo.txt");
$zip->close();
```

Comment: have you checked if the test.txt and helllo.txt are in the same folder or even exists?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same folder which is a child folder of the folder holding the file in php.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I did not put the full path from the initial folder in the first parameter.

Comment: I don't think that would solve your problem, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this instead:

```
<?php

/* Create zip folder */
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zipCreate = $zip->open("newarchive.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);

if($zipCreate !== TRUE) {
    die("Zip folder creation failed");
}

$directory = getcwd() . '/';

$files = array('test.txt', 'helllo.txt');

foreach($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($directory . $file, basename($file));
}

$zip->close();
```

In the first argument of the `addFile()` method, provide the full path of your file name, and in the second provide a directory/location of your file with in the archive and that should do the trick.

Comment: I like the idea of the array especially.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. Good Job.